# Display variation price inside add to cart button (woocommerce + wp 6.1)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Can you please help on how to display a variable's product price inside the add to cart button instead of poping up under the variation select drop down?

[image]

Tried different codes found but no luck so far.

Cheers

Tried every code found on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this code in your functions.php file:

This will add the product price inside the add-to-cart button.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'kb_custom_add_to_cart_price', 20, 2); // Single product pages
function kb_custom_add_to_cart_price($button_text, $product)
{
    // Variable products
    if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
        // shop and archives
        if (!is_product()) {

            $product_price = wc_price(wc_get_price_to_display($product, array('price' => $product->get_variation_price())));
            return $button_text;
        }
        // Single product pages
        else {
            $variations_data = []; // Initializing

            // Loop through variations data
            foreach ($product->get_available_variations() as $variation) {
                // Set for each variation ID the corresponding price in the data array (to be used in jQuery)
                $variations_data[$variation['variation_id']] = $variation['display_price'];
            }
            ?>
        <script>
            jQuery(function($) {
                var jsonData = <?php echo json_encode($variations_data); ?>,
                    inputVID = 'input.variation_id';

                $('input').change( function(){
                    if( '' != $(inputVID).val() ) {
                        var vid      = $(inputVID).val(), // VARIATION ID
                        vprice   = ''; // Initilizing

                        // Loop through variation IDs / Prices pairs
                        $.each( jsonData, function( index, price ) {
                            if( index == $(inputVID).val() ) {
                                vprice = Math.round(price); // The right variation price
                            }
                        });
                        // Change price dynamically when changing options
                        $( "button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt span" ).remove();
                        $(".single_add_to_cart_button").append("<span>" + "&nbsp;" + vprice + " €" + "</span>");
                    }
                });
            });
            </script><?php
return $button_text;
        }
    }
    // All other product types
    else {
        $product_price = wc_price(wc_get_price_to_display($product));
        return $button_text;
    }
}
```

After that remove the product price under the dropdown:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'kb_hide_product_variable_price', 8);
function kb_hide_product_variable_price()
{
    global $product;

    if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
        ?>
        <style> .woocommerce .price, .woocommerce-page .price { display: none; } </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){

            // On selected variation event
            $('form.variations_form').on('show_variation', function(){
                $('.woocommerce .price').hide('fast');
            });

            // On unselected (or not selected) variation event
            $('form.variations_form').on('hide_variation', function(){
                $('.woocommerce .price').show('fast');
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats an amazing solution and worked like a charm!! Thank you so much buddy. I only have a question, would it be easy for this code to be modified and update the price if someone selected more than one in quantity? Cheers!

Comment: Welcome :) I will try that thing and let you know.

Comment: Hello Krunal! Did you had the chance to have a look at it? Cheers!

Comment: This works fantastic and is really useful for variation products, how would i modify it to show a simple product's price on the add to cart button in the same way.