# Display woocommerce price in the add to cart button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

i'd like to display the woocommerce price in the Add to cart button.

the code on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74413136/display-variation-price-inside-add-to-cart-button-woocommerce-wp-6-1/76052868#76052868) works for the variations but not a simple product. any ideas how I modify it to work on a simple product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'your_slug_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );
function your_slug_add_to_cart_text( $text, $product ) {
    return sprintf( '%s - %s', $text,  strip_tags( wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) ) ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the detail page of simple products:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'add_to_cart_price_for_simple_product', 20, 2 );
/**
 * For the detail page of simple products.
 */
function add_to_cart_price_for_simple_product( $button_text, $product ) {
    // For Simple products.
    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
        $product_price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) );
        return $button_text . ' - Just ' . strip_tags( $product_price );
    } else {
        $product_price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) );
        return $button_text;
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hide_product_simple_price', 8 );
/**
 * Hide the default price section on the detail page.
 */
function hide_product_simple_price() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
        ?>
        <style> .woocommerce .price, .woocommerce-page .price { display: none; } </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great thanks, how would i go about adding a span around the price, it was simple in the original example but with this i believe the strip_tags means it's not possible!